# Hide all LibVLCSharp elements

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, libvlcsharp

I'm developing an app that has live video,
I managed to implement **LibVLCSharp**, but I have a problem, I need to remove everything from the screen, this is just missing:

[image: Remove the numbers from this screen and the band]

Here is my code:

**XAML**

```
<shared:MediaPlayerElement
    x:Name="MediaPlayerElementPlayer"
    EnableRendererDiscovery="True"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    LibVLC="{Binding LibVLC}"
    MediaPlayer="{Binding MediaPlayer}"
    VerticalOptions="Start">
    <shared:MediaPlayerElement.PlaybackControls>
        <shared:PlaybackControls
            IsAspectRatioButtonVisible="False"
            IsAudioTracksSelectionButtonVisible="False"
            IsCastButtonVisible="False"
            IsClosedCaptionsSelectionButtonVisible="False"
            IsPlayPauseButtonVisible="False"
            IsRewindButtonVisible="False"
            IsSeekBarVisible="False"
            IsSeekButtonVisible="False"
            IsSeekEnabled="False"
            IsStopButtonVisible="False"
            KeepScreenOn="False"
            MainColor="{StaticResource Cor8}"
            ShowAndHideAutomatically="True" />
    </shared:MediaPlayerElement.PlaybackControls>
</shared:MediaPlayerElement>
```

**C#**

```
private void ConstruirLibVLC()
{
    Core.Initialize();

    Contexto.LibVLC = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs: true);

    Media media = new Media(Contexto.LibVLC, new Uri(TransmissaoAoVivoHelper.UrlTransmissaoAoVivo));
    Contexto.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media) 
    { 
        EnableHardwareDecoding = true,                    
    };

    media.Dispose();
    Contexto.MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. If you want to have only the video player, why not using the VideoView element instead of MediaPlayerElement (which is a view that already embeds commonly-used controls, like buttons, a seekbar...)

Comment: Yes, I just need the video to appear.

My file is ".flv", with VideoView I can play this file?

thanks for the help

Comment: Yes. If you only need to display video, just use the `VideoView` and remove `MediaPlayerElement` from your code

Comment: @mfkl Thanks, I got what I wanted! congratulations for the work.